# How do I identify the amount of RAM on a Video Card (GPU)?

Tags: memory, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, gpu

Which ways are there for me to determine the amount of memory (GRAM) my graphics card has?

Let's suppose I have an `Nvidia Quadro FX1800`.

The OS can be Windows or Linux, there is no sticker on the card and I don't have the package anymore.

Comment: On Windows, the easiest way would be to use `dxdiag`. Once you run the `.exe` you can go to the display tab, see the name of your graphics device, and the approximate total memory.

Comment: @DrZoo Good addition, this needs direct X to be installed, correct?

Comment: Yes, but directX comes with all modern versions of Windows by default so you won’t have any manual installation to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 1. Identify memory using Google

This is the simplest approach, but isn't always accurate. There are many GPUs that come with different memory sizes. In the case of the `FX1800` however there seems to be only one result. Nvidia's website shows the memory for each GPU under the "specifications" tab:
[image]

## 2. Linux solution - Nvidia GPUs only

This requires the use of the `nvidia` driver (and/or CUDA):

```
$ nvidia-smi

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 396.45                 Driver Version: 396.45                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 660     Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
| 38%   55C    P2    N/A /  N/A |   1260MiB /  1991MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

In the second column it says `1260MiB / 1991MiB` - `1991MiB` being your GPU's RAM.

## 3. Linux solution - All GPUs

This works for all kinds of GPUs, as long as you use `xorg`/`xserver`:

```
grep -i --color memory /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

This command will query the `xorg` server-log for your GPU's memory information:

```
[    24.636] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 2097152 kBytes
[    24.724] (II) NVIDIA: Using 6144.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory
[    24.804] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
```

This tells us my GPU has `2097152 kBytes` - So it's basically a 2GB Memory GPU.

## 4. Windows Powershell solution - All GPUs

This solution was originally suggested in a comment by [HelpingHand](https://superuser.com/users/682835/helpinghand).

To get results only for Nvidia GPUs, run the following command in a powershell window:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_VideoController -filter "name like '%NVIDIA%'" | select AdapterRAM,@{Expression={$_.adapterram/1MB};label="MB"}
```

To get results for all graphic cards, the following command can be used:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_VideoController | select name, AdapterRAM,@{Expression={$_.adapterram/1MB};label="MB"}
```

Of course you can also get your GPU's RAM under windows using the regular control panel, looking for "Display Adapter Properties" under `System -> Display` on Windows 10.

Comment: On Windows CPU-Z is also a nice freeware tool to get detailed info on CPU, MB, RAM and GPU. https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html

Comment: I don't have the `Get-WmiObject` comdlet in pwsh. So how to install it?

Comment: Sadly the "Linux solution" is not a Linux solution but an X.org solution and that won't work on Wayland.

Answer (score 1):

```
$qwMemorySize = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0*" -Name HardwareInformation.qwMemorySize -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)."HardwareInformation.qwMemorySize"
$VRAM = [math]::round($qwMemorySize/1GB)
Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_VideoController | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.AdapterDACType -ne "Internal"} | ForEach-Object -Process {
    [PSCustomObject] @{
        Model = $_.Caption
        "VRAM, GB" = $VRAM
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice! Best answer, not requiring additional tools or installing extra commandlets.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, another way is to see what the kernel reports during booting:

```sh
sudo dmesg | grep VRAM
```

For example with an AMD chip:

```
[    4.798391] amdgpu 0000:09:00.0: amdgpu: VRAM: 4096M 0x000000F400000000 - 0x000000F4FFFFFFFF (4096M used)
[    4.798400] [drm] Detected VRAM RAM=4096M, BAR=256M
[    4.798436] [drm] amdgpu: 4096M of VRAM memory ready
```